# Checkbox in header will be checked if all child checkboxes are checked and unchecked when even one of them is unchecked in C# Desktop Application

Tags: c#, .net

I have a datagridview in C# .net Windows Application where one checkbox column is there and i have added a header checkbox .

code for adding a header checkbox and checkbox column is

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn c1;
CheckBox ckBox;

private void CheckboxSelect_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
c1 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
c1.Name = "selection";
c1.HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

this.dgvSelectAll.Columns.Add(c1);
this.dgvSelectAll.Rows.Add();
this.dgvSelectAll.Rows.Add();
this.dgvSelectAll.Rows.Add();
this.dgvSelectAll.Rows.Add();

ckBox = new CheckBox();
Rectangle rect =this.dgvSelectAll.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, true);
ckBox.Size = new Size(18, 18);
ckBox.Location = rect.Location;
this.dgvSelectAll.Controls.Add(ckBox);
}
```

Is it possible If All check boxes are checked then header Checkbox will be checked and among the checked checkboxes one is unchecked then header will be unchecked in C#.Net Windows Application??

Comment: It can surely be done but there is an issue.. Whenever you check the check box in the datagridview, then a new row is getting added automatically. i tried your code. Because of this whenever u check a checkbox then there will always be one checkbox that is unchecked. I think if u solve that issue then its very easy to achieve what you are asking for. and an easier implementation of this would is when you use the treeview rather than gridview.i.e., only if you want checkboxes. its simple that way.

Comment: A new row will not be automatically added if you try this code         private void dgvSelectAll_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {if (e.RowIndex == 4)
                dgvSelectAll.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        }} and make AllowUserToAddRows =false

Comment: And is it mandatory to use datagridview??? why not treeview?

Comment: datagridview is not mandatory but in my application the datagridview contains one Checkboxcolumn and one  Textboxcolumn , and i have to show both the checkboxcolumn  and the Textboxcolumn  ,that's why i use datagridview but if you have any other solution then please provide

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 void dgvSelectAl_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cellCheck = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dgvSelectAl[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
            if (cellCheck != null)
            {
                if ((bool)cellCheck.Value == true)
                {
                    checkBoxCounter++;
                }
                else
                {
                    checkBoxCounter--;
                }
            }
            if (checkBoxCounter == dgvSelectAl.Rows.Count-1)
            {
                ckBox.Checked = true;
            }
            else if (checkBoxCounter != dgvSelectAl.Rows.Count-1)
            {
                ckBox.Checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
```